# build.properties equivalent in puppet?

Tags: java, ant, puppet

When you build something in ANT for Java, you can include a properties file that different values can be read from during the build.

Is it possible to do something similar with Puppet?  Like for instance, if I want to have the database password and username set to the same thing in both the database when the puppet agent catalog runs on an agent?

Comment: The example you gave clashes with the functionality you are describing so it is unclear what you are asking here. That being said, the functionality you want as you describe it seems to be referencing Hiera: https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MattSchuchard commented, [Hiera](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/) is Puppet's mechanism for storing and retrieving static data for use during catalog building.  It is deeper and more powerful than Ant's `build.properties`, in that it

- directly supports [data types](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/data_sources.html#data-format) other than strings
- provides for [**hiera**rchical / layered data](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/hierarchy.html) definition
- can [reference the context from which data retrievals are performed](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/variables.html#interpolation-tokens)
- interacts with Puppet class parameters to provide for [automatic data binding](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup)
- supports multiple data storage back-ends, including [user-defined ones](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/custom_backends.html#writing-custom-backends)

, among other things.

There's a lot more that could be said, but if all you want is to use Hiera data analogously to data from an Ant `build.properties` file, then the main things you need to know are that the built-in back-ends provide for YAML and JSON format instead of Java .properties format, and that your manifests can access the data by passing the key for the requested item to the [`hiera()`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.8/function.html#hiera) function.  The Puppet documentation for your version of Puppet will have more to say about where to put the data file(s) and how to configure Puppet to use them.